# How to efficiently compute euclidean distance matrices without for loops in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (51266,20,25,3) (N,F,J,C) matrix, where N is the example number, F is the frame number, J is the joint, and C is the xyz coordinates of the joint. I want to calculate the euclidean distance matrix for each frame in each example to  have a matrix of dimensions (51266,20,25,25) My code is

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances as euc
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
Examples = np.load('allExamples.npy')
theEuclideanMethod = np.zeros((0,20,25,25))
for example in tqdm(range(Examples.shape[0])):
  euclideanBox = np.zeros((0,25,25))
  for frame in range(20):
    euclideanBox = np.concatenate((euclideanBox,euc(Examples[example,frame,:,:])[np.newaxis,...]),axis=0)

  euclideanBox = euclideanBox[np.newaxis,...]
  theEuclideanMethod = np.concatenate((theEuclideanMethod,euclideanBox))

np.save("Euclidean examples.npy",theEuclideanMethod)
print(theEuclideanMethod.shape,"Euclidean shape")
```

The problem is I'm using for loops which are super slow. What are other ways I can modify my code to run faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should run pretty fast. Float32 used to keep the memory usage low, but is optional. Adjust `batch_size` to be greater for increased speed or lower for less memory usage.

```py
import numpy as np

# Adjust batch_size depending on your memory
batch_size = 500

# Make some fake data
x = np.random.randn(51266,20,25,3).astype(np.float32)
y = np.random.randn(51266,20,25,3).astype(np.float32)

# distance_matrix
d = np.empty(x.shape[:-1] + (x.shape[-2],), dtype=np.float32)
# Number of batches
N = (x.shape[0]-1) // batch_size + 1
for i in range(N):
    d[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] = np.sqrt(np.sum((
        x[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,:,:,None] - \
        y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size,:,None,:])**2, axis=-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array broadcasting, like this:

```
import numpy as np

examples = np.random.uniform(size=(5, 6, 7, 3))
N, F, J, C = examples.shape

# deltas.shape == (N, F, J, J, C) - Cartesian deltas
deltas  = examples.reshape(N, F, J, 1, C) - examples.reshape(N, F, 1, J, C)

# distances.shape == (N, F, J, J)
distances = np.sqrt((deltas**2).sum(axis=-1), dtype=np.float32)

del deltas # release memory (only needed for interactive use)
```

This is a bit memory-hungry: with the values of N, F, J, C that you mentioned, the intermediate results (`deltas`) will take 16 GB, assuming double precision. It will be more efficient (6x less memory and better use of cache) if you preallocate the output array in single precision and loop over the N axis:

```
distances = np.empty((N, F, J, J))

for i, ex in enumerate(examples):
    # deltas.shape = (F, J, J, C) - Cartesian deltas
    deltas = ex.reshape(F, J, 1, C) - ex.reshape(F, 1, J, C)
    distances[i] = np.sqrt((deltas**2).sum(axis=-1))
```